# conversion from 'float' to 'LONG' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++

I'm working on a old project that I decided to pick up, when I left it I don't remember having any issues. How ever, now it seems like I have. I do get the following error: I am not sure how to fix that as I am still rather new to c++

> conversion from 'float' to 'LONG' requires a narrowing conversion

```
> this->TextPosition = RECT{ Position.left + 3, Position.top + Height/2
> + CMyWindow::FontHeight/2 + 3, Position.right, Position.bottom };
```

Comment: `float` is just a standard type, but it seems that `LONG` isn't. What is `LONG`?

Comment: @ForceBru Probably `long`.

Comment: It is a proper warning, not all possible *float* values can be converted to a 32-bit integer.  Use a cast to tell the compiler that you know better and that a font height is never a bizarrely large value.  Although +3 is winging it rather a bit, you ought to round that up.  And checking that it is pixels instead of points certainly shouldn't hurt either.  Plenty of good reasons to give you a warning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may using cast to mute this warning:

```
... RECT{ static_cast<LONG>(Position.left + 3), ... and next fileds too
```